# Copying a once compiled folder from shared drive into own workspace in a docker image

Tags: linux, docker, caffe

I am a user of a docker iamge on a server. On this server the caffe framework is installed on the "shared" side so that every docker image is able to access this framework without needing it to install themselves.

However, I want to make changes in one python script (e.g the draw_net.py) which is located in a python folder. I now want to copy the files to my own workspace and continue working with them, and only change the draw_net.py but make this file use the compiled data (otherwise I would have to compile it my own, which is a little painful). However since I do not own these files I am not able to change them, therefore I wanted to copy one file into my container and change it, but the dependencies must be still kept up, this is where I run into errors. I do not want to recompile anything on my image, I just want to change one python script a little.

The structure looks like the following:

```
bin/
dev/
home/ 
lib64/
mnt/
proc/
run/
srv/
tmp/
var/
boot/
etc/
lib/
media/
opt/
 caffe/
  build/
   lib/
    _caffe.so
  data/
  docker/
  examples/
  matlab/
  python/
   caffe/
     __init__.py
     __init__.pyc
     pycaffe.py
     pycaffe.pyc
   draw_net.py
  src/
  cmake/
  distribute/
  docs/
  include/
  models/
  scripts/
  tools/
root/ 
 workspace/
  myfolder/ 
sbin/
sys/
usr/
```

Now I want the files from `/opt/caffe/python/` , especially the `draw_net.py` in my own docker image are, so in `/root/workspace/myfolder`.

A simple `cp` command resulted in the following errors

> cp: cannot create symbolic link 'cpcaffe/build' Operation not
>   supported
>
> cp: cannot create symbolic link 'cpcaffe/python/caffe/_caffe.so': Operation not supported

Executing gives me the expected reseult that it cannot located the moduel `_caffe` , which is located in /opt/caffe/build/lib/_caffe.so

I tried to add the line

```
import os
os.chdir('/opt/caffe/python');
```

at the beginning of the script but this did not change anything.

I guess that I somehow to make a symbolic link by myself to the original version, but I am a little newbish around this topic and could need some pointers.

I have root access to all folders under root/ , all other folders are shared folders where I only have read rights.

Comment: You'll need to give us more info. What does your directory structure look like? What is the shared drive really? Where is located, where is mounted? What "data" do you not want to compile again? Where is the data located? Where are you trying to copy the contents of the folder to?

Please attach the output of `tree` from inside the container for the relevant folders, the output of `docker info` in addition to the stuff requested above.

Comment: Thank you, I added the information I could find however I was unable to run the command docker info (command not found)

Comment: the docker info command needs to be run on the host machine where the container is actually run.

Comment: Sorry I edited my post to make it clearer that I am only the user of a docker image and hence have no access to the machine itself

Comment: can you please tell me if you have root inside the container and which of the folders are shared and which aren't? To do what you want, you'll probably have to hack around the $PYTHONPATH to override the one script.

Comment: Sorry for the additional comment, but I think this is needed as well: How's caffe installed? I see the python files and compiled .so files, but is that the build directory and it's pip installed somewhere or do you directly import from that location? What's the `import` statement look like in your code?

Comment: I have root access inside my container, all files under root/ are mine , all others are shared., my current PYTHONPATH is /opt/caffe/python. 

Sadly, I do not really know how it was build - but I am pretty sure it was build manually and not via pip install. 

The import looks like this:

import caffe 

Which directs to a __init__.py file which tries to include ._caffe

Comment: long story short, I merged all need py files into one file instead of importing them and made the one file executable. This is an ugly hack but it works. Thanks for your time and attention

Comment: If your `PYTHONPATH` points to `/opt/caffe/python` then what might work for you is to simply copy the one file that you want to change in a different directory in your workspace, such as `/root/workspace/caffe_patches`, edit that file, and then prepend that path into your `PYTHONPATH` so that it looks something like this - `/root/workspace/caffe_patches:/opt/caffe/python`. This is still a hack, but if it works, it's a cleaner one.

Comment: Sadly this will not quite work - I just found out that the file I want to change is not the file which is executed but a file which gets included. But this file lays in a folder which other dependend files and I cannot delet it. So somehow it would see two versions of the same file and one had to make sure that it uses the correct one, some kind of priority mechanism

Comment: that is exactly what prepending your own folder to `PYTHONPATH` will do. Python has a very specific search order as outlined here - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path . If there are two files with the same name, the one found in the search path first is the one that is used. You are essentially "overriding" the default file with your own version.

Comment: Sadly, it used the old file before and not the new one in the patch folder

Comment: Oh, sad. I don't think I can help any more over without being at the terminal directly. Sorry :/

Comment: Thanks for helping